# How can I update values in a Map, maintaining the order

Tags: java, collections

I have a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator`. I want to update one of the values of the Map, but if the fields checked by the `Comparator` are changed, does the Map keep its order?

Comment: How are you updating the value? Are you using `put` to replace a value, or are you modifying the `Object` directly?

Comment: you changed the key or value?

Comment: Hopefully you are not using the broken monstrosity of Comparator that sorts on entry values.

Comment: I am modifying the Object directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never modify keys stored in a map. Or at least not modify any of the fields used to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` (in the case of a HashMap) or `compareTo()`/`compare()` (in the case of a SortedMap).

This will put the map in an inconsistent state, and you can't expect it to work reliably after doing that.

Of course, you can remove the key from the map, modify it, and then reinsert it.

But you'd better use immutable types as keys of your maps, to avoid shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the solution. I can insert the modified Object with the same key and it will update the Map. Thanks.

Comment: If all you do is modify the _value_ -- not the key -- then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman But the position in the `Map` depends on the value, so the `Map` needs to be updated.

Comment: @user1911149: no, the position in the map depends on the keys. Unless of course some of the values are also keys.

Comment: Or if you're using a `Comparator` that pretends to compare the keys but actually compares the values; that's _evil_ and breaky for precisely this reason (among many, many others).